# ifstream usage and user input not outputting content to read

Tags: c++, while-loop, do-while, ifstream

I'm practicing `ifstream` usage. I want the user to enter the file they want to read, in this example **num1.txt** specifically. I want the console to read one letter from `num1.txt` and output it on its own line.

I've ran the code below, and after entering `"num1.txt"` into the console, I get nothing back. I've tried moving around `cout << num << endl;` to the inner `do` statement, but it ends up repeating the number `10` an infinite amount.

What am I doing wrong here?

Contents in `num1.txt`:

```
2 4 6 8 10
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string fileName, cont;
    ifstream inputFile;

    do {
        int num = 0;
        int total = 0;
        cout << "Please enter the file name: ";
        cin >> fileName;
        inputFile.open(fileName);

        if (inputFile.is_open()) {
            do {
                inputFile >> num;
                total += num; 
            }
            while(num > 0);

            if (total != 0) {
                cout << num << endl;
                cout << "Total is: " << total << endl;
            }
        }
        else {
            cout << "Failed to open file." << endl;
        }

        inputFile.close();
        cout << "Do you want to continue processing files? (yes or no): " << endl;
        cin >> cont;
    }
    while (cont == "yes");
}
```

Comment: `while(num > 0);` -> `while(inputFile);` ?

Comment: Your loop will end when `num <= 0`. Did you mean to stop when all of `inputFile` is read?

Comment: @scohe001 Yeah, I want it to stop when all of it is read.

Comment: @scohe001 when I do while(inputFile); it reads the last number twice, any help?

Comment: While practicing remember that it's a lot easier to debug when your code look at the return code. In the case of streams, the return code is the stream itself. You should almost never `stream >> some_var;`. Instead you should have something along the lines of `if (stream >> some_var) { use some_var} else { report error and clean up the mess }`. Especially when the stream is controlled by a user. Users are scum. There are a lot of users out there to trash your program for fun and profit and the rest of them are idiots who can't hit the right key most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Your inner `do` loop is not correctly validating that `operator>>` is actually successful before using `num`.  It should be looking at the stream's error state after each read.  The easiest way to do that is to change your `do` loop into a `while` loop that uses the result of the read as its loop condition, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string fileName, cont;
    ifstream inputFile;

    do {
        cout << "Please enter the file name: ";
        cin >> fileName;
        inputFile.open(fileName);

        if (inputFile.is_open()) {
            int num = 0;
            int total = 0;
            while (inputFile >> num) {
                total += num; 
            }
            inputFile.close();
            cout << "Total is: " << total << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Failed to open file." << endl;
        }

        cout << "Do you want to continue processing files? (yes or no): " << endl;
    }
    while ((cin >> cont) && (cont == "yes"));
    return 0;
}
```